# LIBMODBUS: Writing to a double register?

Tags: c, modbus

Is there a way I can write one value to a double register using `LIBMODBUS`? For example writing value `100,000` to be spread across one register. Currently using `modbus_write_registers` to write `10,000` I am sending the modbus message

```
rc = modbus_write_registers(ctx, 4, 2, tab_reg); (Where tab_reg[0] = 10,000 and tab_reg[1] = 0)


0A 10 00 04 00 02 04 27 10 00 00 DC 09
```

Ideally the message i believe I would like to send would not send the `00 00` for the zero value. Is this possible to utilise using Libmodbus?

NB - I have also attempted using modbus_write_register() and this produced a much longer message so I am inclined to believe write registerS is the way to go.

Comment: `rc = modbus_write_registers(ctx, 4, 1, tab_reg);`..... BTW I guess you are seeing something weird: `modbus_write_register` should send a shorter message because write a single Holding register (message code 0x06) instead of two (message code 0x10).

Comment: That gives me the following message: "0A 10 00 04 00 01 02 27 10 CE D8 0A 10 00 04 00 01 41 73" what is following the checksum here?

Comment: Actually it looks like it is repeating part of the message which must write to register 4 the value 41 73; however I have not written this anywhere in my code.

Comment: `10 00 04 00 01 02 27 10 CE D8` is your message `10 00 04 00 01 41 73` is the answer from slave

Comment: @LPs Ah, I see. Doesnt this mean that I have written the value 4173 to the register? which was not what I intended

Comment: Answer from slave is ack: `10` message code, `00 04` start address, `00 01` number of registers wrote, `41 73` CRC

Comment: Take a look at this [protocol specs](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b.pdf) page 30 and 31

Comment: I guess you are seeing both messages due to `RS485` line

Comment: Surely this would not work though? As Im trying to write to a double (32-bit) register using functions that only allow for 16 bit data and only specifying 1 register.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting you. Using `rc = modbus_write_registers(ctx, 4, 2, tab_reg);` you are writing 2 holding registers that are 4 bytes (16 bit each). So what is you problem with that?

Comment: I would like to write to 1, 32 bit register at address 4. If that is possible using libmodbus

Comment: There is something not clear. ModBus Holding Registers are 16 bit. There isn't 32 bits registers. Using the code you posted you are writing a 32 bit value starting from address `0004` .